# Trigger ON Table which fire INSERT into another table which has NOT NULL constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER logaction ON temployeelog
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TABLE temployee(ename, experience)
    SELECT ename,experience FROM INSERTED
END
```

The structure of temployee

```
CREATE TABLE temployee
(
  ename VARCHAR(20),
  experience INT NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE temployeeADD  DEFAULT (0) FOR experience
```

When I don't pass data in the experience column WHILE INSERT I get an error.

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'experience', table
>   'temployee'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement
>   has been terminated.

I wanted to pass NULL Values temployeelog table AND wanted those situation to be handled by 'DEFAULT VALUES kept in temployee'

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table default only comes into play if you don't insert it, so split the insert into one which handles a `non-null` experience and one which handles a `null` experience

```
INSERT INTO TABLE temployee (ename, experience)
  SELECT ename, experience
  FROM INSERTED
  WHERE experience IS NOT NULL;

INSERT INTO TABLE temployee (ename)
  SELECT ename
  FROM INSERTED
  WHERE experience IS NULL;
```