# Trigger ON Table which fire INSERT into another table which has NOT NULL constraint , which has float datatype

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER studenttr ON tstudentlog
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO TABLE tstudent(sname, marks)
SELECT sname,marks FROM INSERTED


END
```

The structure of tstudent

```
CREATE TABLE tstudent
(
name VARCHAR(20),
marks FLOAT NOT NULL

)

ALTER TABLE tstudent ADD  DEFAULT (0) FOR marks
```

When I don't pass data in the marks column WHILE INSERTING record into tstudentlog

I get an error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'marks', table 'tstudent'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

I tried the following but did not work

```
INSERT INTO TABLE tstudent(sname)
  SELECT sname
  FROM INSERTED
  where marks is null;
```

I wanted to pass NULL Values tstudent table AND wanted those situdation to be handled by 'DEFAULT VALUES kept in tstudent'

How can I achieve that?

Comment: How about doing `where marks is` **`NOT`** `null;` ...

Comment: then I should pass some value in MARKS field, then  it will  be captured by where marks is NOT null; I wanted to pass NULL, but it will throw an error because of the NOT NULL contraint on column marks

Comment: So why isn't this a duplicate of your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53439620/trigger-on-table-which-fire-insert-into-another-table-which-has-not-null-constra) asked 12 hours ago?

Comment: For columns with different datatypes I was having issues

Comment: Why are you mix and matching datatypes?

Comment: Am I reading this correct that you create a new student when you log something about a user in table `studentlog` ? Should that not be the other way around ? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger ON Table which fire INSERT into another table which has NOT NULL constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53439620/trigger-on-table-which-fire-insert-into-another-table-which-has-not-null-constra)

Comment: Yes , That's right .. That was a typo.Issue I was getting an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a lot of problem with default values in table, 
It could go well to use coalesce on insert statement?

```
CREATE TRIGGER studenttr ON tstudentlog
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO TABLE tstudent(sname, marks)
SELECT sname,coalesce(marks,0) FROM INSERTED


END
```